# misconception about how prolog works

Tags: prolog

So I am currently learning prolog and I can't get my head around how this language works.
"It tries all the possible solutions until it finds one, if it doesn't it returns false" is what I've read that this language does. You just *Describe* the solution and it finds it for you

With that in mind, I am trying to solve the 8 queens problem ( how to place 8 queens on a chess board without anyone threatening the others).
I have this predicate, 'safe' that gets a list of pairs, the positions of all the queens and succeeds when they are not threatening each other.

When I enter in the terminal

```
 ?- safe([(1,2),(3,5)]).
true ?
| ?- safe([(1,3),(1,7)]).
no
| ?- safe([(2,2),(3,3)]).
no
| ?- safe([(2,2),(3,4),(8,7)]).
true ?
```

it recognizes the correct from the wrong answers, so it knows if something is a possible solution

**BUT**

when I enter

```
| ?- safe(L).

L = [] ? ;

L = [_] ? ;
```

it gives me the default answers, even though it recognizes a solution for 2 queens when I enter them.

here is my code

```
threatens((_,Row),(_,Row)).
threatens((Column,_),(Column,_)).
threatens((Column1,Row1),(Column2,Row2)) :-
    Diff1 is Column1 - Row1,
    Diff2 is Column2 - Row2,
    abs(Diff1) =:= abs(Diff2).

safe([]).
safe([_]).

safe([A,B|T]) :-
    \+ threatens(A,B),
    safe([A|T]),
    safe(T).
```

One solution I found to the problem is to create predicates 'position' and modify the 'safe' one

```
possition((0,0)).
possition((1,0)).
...
...
possition((6,7)).
possition((7,7)).

safe([A,B|T]) :-
    possition(A),
    possition(B),
    \+ threatens(A,B),
    safe([A|T]),
    safe(T).

safe(L,X):-
    length(L,X),
    safe(L).
```

but this is just stupid, as you have to type everything explicitly and really really slow,
even for  6 queens.

My real problem here, is not with the code itself but with prolog, I am trying to think in prolog, But all I read is
**Describe how the solution would look like and let it work out what is would be**
Well that's what I have been doing but it does not seem to work,
Could somebody point me to some resources that don't teach you the semantics but how to think in prolog
Thank you

Comment: you say "One solution I found to the problem ...." but what is that problem? it seems you're asking too many questions at once (so it needs more focus), but as a matter of fact I can't find even one question in your post. "why doesn't it work" is too broad a question. asking one focused specific question at a time is really much better for you to learn that way since the answers will be focused and comprehensible for you, too. :) (this is not to say anything about the existing answer since I wrote this comment before it was posted)

Comment: @WillNess Go ahead Will, say what you mean :-)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I just meant I was making a point that an answer is impossible, but as I was writing it you posted something... (and I suspect it's above their current level of understanding...)

Comment: Of interest: [Solving N-queens with Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/queens/)

Answer (score 4):

> but this is just stupid, as you have to type everything explicitly and really really slow, even for 6 queens.

Regarding listing the positions, the two coordinates are independent, so you could write something like:

```
position((X, Y)) :-
    coordinate(X),
    coordinate(Y).

coordinate(1).
coordinate(2).
...
coordinate(8).
```

This is already much less typing. It's even simpler if your Prolog has a `between/3` predicate:

```
coordinate(X) :-
    between(1, 8, X).
```

Regarding the predicate being very slow, this is because you are asking it to do too much duplicate work:

```
safe([A,B|T]) :-
    ...
    safe([A|T]),
    safe(T).
```

Once you know that `[A|T]` is safe, `T` must be safe as well. You can remove the last goal and will get an exponential speedup.

Comment: yeah you are right about the coordinates, but safe only examines if the first two element threaten each other, so if i keep only safe([A|T]), it will only see if the first queen of the initial list is safe, but will not examine if the third threatens the fourth. For example if the initial list has 3 queens [A,B,C] and I only keep safe([A|T]) first it will look if threatens(A,B) and then it will see if safe([A,C]) but, it won't look into threatens (B,C).

Comment: [as I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643532/misconception-about-how-prolog-works/62654883#comment110783065_62643532), impossible to answer, here evident for the third reason, of the question not including all the relevant code. we *don't know* how `safe` is used, so can't  really refute the OP's rebuttal. :(

Comment: No, @Iliasp is correct, their implementation of `safe` only checks neighboring queens. I absolutely overlooked this, and if we read more carefully than I did, then it's clear from the code of `safe`, no matter how it's used. But adding a `safe(T)` goal doesn't change this. Rather, `safe` should be rewritten to call *another* predicate that ensures that `A` does not threaten any queen in `T`. In an imperative language the check would use two nested loops, so in Prolog it must use two distinct predicates.

Comment: yeah now i got what you meant, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

> Describe how the solution would look like and let it work out what is
> would be

demands that the AI be very strong in general. We are not there yet.

You are on the right track though. Prolog essentially works by enumerating possible solutions and testing them, rejecting those that don't fit the conditions encoded in the program. The skill resides in performing a "good enumeration" (traversing the domain in certain ways, exploiting domain symmetries and overlaps etc) and subsequent "fast rejection" (quickly throwing away whole sectors of the search space as not promising). The basic pattern:

```
findstuff(X) :- generate(X),test(X).
```

And evidently the program must first generate `X` before it can test `X`, which may not be always evident to beginners.

Logic-wise,

```
findstuff(X) :- x_fulfills_test_conditions(X),x_fullfills_domain_conditions(X).
```

which is really another way of writing

```
findstuff(X) :- test(X),generate(X).
```

would be the same, but for Prolog, as a concrete implementation, there would be nothing to work with.

That `X` in the program always stands for a particular value (which may be uninstantiated at a given moment, but becomes more and more instantiated going "to the right"). Unlike in logic, where the `X` really stands for an unknown object onto which we pile constraints until -ideally- we can resolve `X` to a set of concrete values by applying a lot of thinking to reformulate constraints.

Which brings us the the approach of "Constraint Logic Programming (over finite domains)", aka `CLP(FD)` which is far more elegant and nearer what's going on when thinking mathematically or actually doing theorem proving, see here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming

and the ECLiPSe logic programming system

http://eclipseclp.org/

and

- https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpz
- https://github.com/triska/clpfd/blob/master/n_queens.pl
- **[N-Queens in Prolog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_tbL9RjFdo) on YouTube.** as a must-watch

This is still technically Prolog (in fact, implemented on top of Prolog) but allows you to work on a more abstract level than raw generate-and-test.

Comment: hey there, thank you, this was close to what I was looking for, If I got this right, what you were saying is that i got the  "test" part correct, now i just have to generate some answers for prolog to test them, right? That is what I though about when writing all the positions, but it still seems kinda odd. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Prolog is radically different in its approach to computing.
Arithmetic often is not required at all. But the complexity inherent in a solution to a problem show up in some place, where we control how relevant information are related.

```erlang
place_queen(I,[I|_],[I|_],[I|_]).
place_queen(I,[_|Cs],[_|Us],[_|Ds]):-place_queen(I,Cs,Us,Ds).

place_queens([],_,_,_).
place_queens([I|Is],Cs,Us,[_|Ds]):-
  place_queens(Is,Cs,[_|Us],Ds),
  place_queen(I,Cs,Us,Ds).

gen_places([],[]).
gen_places([_|Qs],[_|Ps]):-gen_places(Qs,Ps).

qs(Qs,Ps):-gen_places(Qs,Ps),place_queens(Qs,Ps,_,_).

goal(Ps):-qs([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],Ps).
```

No arithmetic at all, columns/rows are encoded in a clever choice of symbols (the numbers indeed are just that, identifiers), diagonals in two additional arguments.

The whole program just requires a (very) small subset of Prolog, namely a pure [2-clauses interpreter](http://www.cse.unt.edu/%7Etarau/research/2017/eng.pdf).

If you take the time to understand what `place_queens/4` does (operationally, maybe, if you have above average attention capabilities), you'll gain a deeper understanding of what (pure) Prolog actually computes.